# doctrine2 OneToMany relationship inserts NULL as the foreign key

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a bi-directional OneToMany relationship using Doctrine 2 as an ORM within the ZendFramework 1.11.2.

Note: Doctrine did not create the database tables. The database is MySQL.

For some reason, when I persist and flush a new link entity to the link table (see below) the foreign key field (container_id) gets set to NULL. However, if the '@' symbol is removed from the  'ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Container\Model", inversedBy="links")' line, the foreign key field is populated properly.

Since the entity is added properly to the database when the '@' symbol is removed, there is something wrong with the OneToMany relationship somewhere.

For example, if I have a link model named $link (see pseudo-code below)...

```
 $link (Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Link\Model) 
    {
        id:   ''      // auto generated value
        cid:  23      // the foreign key value
        label: test   
        uri: test.com 
        ...           // other values not listed here for brevity
    }
```

...when the new link model is persisted and the entity manager is flushed, the container_id (foreign key) value from the newly inserted row in the link (shepherd_navigation_link) table is NULL.

```
    $em // Assume $em is the Entity Manager
    $em->persist($link);
    $em->flush();

    // The container_id in the newly added row in the 
    // link table (shepherd_navigation_link) is NULL
```

The link table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `shepherd_navigation_link` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `container_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `node_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parent_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `label` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `options` text,
  `events` text,
  `privilege` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `resource` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uri` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
  `visible` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `container_id` (`container_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
ALTER TABLE `shepherd_navigation_link` ADD FOREIGN KEY (container_id) REFERENCES shepherd_navigation_container(id)
```

Link entity model:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="shepherd_navigation_link")
 */
class
{
    /** 
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue 
     */
     protected $id;

    /** 
     * @Column(name="container_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
     protected $cid;

    /** 
     * @Column(name="node_id", type="integer")
     */
    protected $nid;

    /** 
     * @Column(name="parent_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     */
    protected $pid;

    /** 
     * @Column
     */
    protected $label;

    /** 
     * @Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $options;

    /** 
     * @Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $events;

    /** 
     * @Column
     */
    protected $privilege;

    /** 
     * @Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $resource;

    /** 
     * @Column
     */
    protected $uri;

    /** 
     * @Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $visible;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Model", mappedBy="parent")
     */
    private $children;

    /**
     * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Model", inversedBy="children")
     */
    private $parent;

    /**
     *) @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Container\Model", inversedBy="links"
     */
    private $container;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Link\Position", inversedBy="link")
     */
    private $node;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->children = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();   
    }

    /** Accessors and Mutators excluded for brevity **/
}
```

Note: the protected property $cid maps to the container_id column above.

The container table schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `shepherd_navigation_container` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB
```

The container entity model:

```
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="shepherd_navigation_container")
 */
class Model
{
    /** 
     * @Id 
     * @Column(type="integer")
     * @GeneratedValue 
     */
    protected $id;

    /** 
     * @Column
     */
    protected $name;

    /** 
     * @Column(nullable=true)
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Link\Model", mappedBy="container")
     */
    private $links;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->links = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }

    /** Accessors and Mutators excluded for brevity **/
}
```

What am I missing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't believe you need the whole path to your target entities in you association mapppings. It looks like on some you have the whole path and on others you have just the entity name. I'm not sure if that is what is causing the problem but it is something you could look at.

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, you're right. I'm inconsistent in my naming the models. But the problem still persists.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured out the problem (by reading the documentation http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/getting-started-xml-edition.html). It turns out there were actually a few problems.

Problem 1 => I did not provide a method to set the container variable.

```
// Inside the Link Entity class...

public function setContainer($container)
{
    $this->container = $container;
}
```

Problem 2 => I did not set the container value. In error, I thought Doctrine 2 did this internally, but I found out the container variable needs to be set prior to flushing.

Foolish oversight on my part.

```
$link = new Link();
$link->setContainer($container);

// $em is the Entity Manager
$em->persist($link);
$em->flush();
```

Problem 3 => The container ($container) needed to either be persisted prior to flushing or the @OneToMany definition on the container entity needed to change. I chose to update the container entity definition. Take a look here (http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations) for more information.

```
// Inside the Container Entity class...
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="Shepherd\Navigation\Domain\Link\Model", mappedBy="container", cascade={"persist"})
 */
```

After making these changes and removing the @OneToOne node relationship in the link entity class (turns out I didn't need it), everything worked fine. I hope this helps someone.