# Doctrine entity one-to-many relationship saves foreign key as NULL

Tags: php, zend-framework, doctrine

I've looked around and this question [doctrine2 OneToMany relationship inserts NULL as the foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5332224/doctrine2-onetomany-relationship-inserts-null-as-the-foreign-key) is similar to this one but without an answer that works for me.

Build in Zend Framework 1.6 using Doctrine 2 and name spaces for classes, Doctrine has build the schema using it's migration tool.

My codes below:

http://pastie.org/3634009

Comment: Why do you expect it to not save the foreign key as NULL?

Comment: Because in the implementation Forum is persisted and flushed and should by this point have an id when adding a Thread to the Forum instance. This has now been resolved, but thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you by some chance miss to "double bind" entities. That is, you need to do for example:

```
$forum = .... // some forum
$thread = .... // new thread;

$forum->getThreads()->add($thread); // first add to list
$thread->setForum($forum); // but also set forum parent within `Thread`
```

and then persist entities as usual...